# Write to a list of files (Xargs but for outputs)

Tags: bash

This is what I intend to do

```bsh
for f in find . -name "*.js"; do
    echo "\n" >> $f
done
```

I want to have a one line solution, but the following will direct the list of file names as arguments and not as the output file.

`find . -name "*.js" | xargs -n1 echo "\n"`

Is there anyway to achieve something like the following?

`find . -name "*.js" | appendToAll -n1 echo "\n"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't state your question, but my interpretation is that you're looking to append a newline to all files ending in `.js`.  If so, this should do that:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec sh -c "echo >> '{}'" \;
```

That's roughly equivalent to your `xargs` solution, but this supports the potential of spaces in the file or path names.

If you *really* want to add two newlines, then:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec sh -c "printf '\n\n' >> '{}'" \;
```